# clear radiobutton list selection using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I would like to clear Radiobutton list selection after user enters the text in the TextBox. I tried the following code but it doesn't seem to be working and it doesn't show any error. Please let me know if there are any suggestions.

```
function ClearRadioButtonList() {
    var checkboxlistid9 = "#<%= rblLst.ClientID %>";
    $('.checkboxlistid9').attr('checked',false);     
}

<telerik:RadMaskedTextBox ID="txtCode" runat="server" Mask="###-##-####" SelectionOnFocus="CaretToBeginning">
    <ClientEvents  OnBlur="ClearRadioButtonList" />
</telerik:RadMaskedTextBox>

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblLst" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Unknown</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Not Applicable</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$('.checkboxlistid9').attr('checked',false);
```

Try:

```
$('.checkboxlistid9').removeAttr('checked');
```

Additionally I think your jQuery selector is wrong

```
$('.checkboxlistid9')
```

I don't see a class `checkboxlistid9` on your `asp:RadioButtonList`

Change the query selector to:

```
$("table[id$=rblLst] input:radio:checked").removeAttr("checked");
```

Or

```
$("table[id$=rblLst] input:radio").each(function (i, x){
    if($(x).is(":checked")){
        $(x).removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks. It's working now. I changed the code to $("table[id$=rblLst] input:radio:checked").removeAttr("checked");

Answer (score 5):

The radio buttons will be descendants of the element that represents the `RadioButtonList`, you can select them with `#<%= rblLst.ClientID %> input[type=radio]` and use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to remove the checked property.

```
function ClearRadioButtonList() {
    $("#<%= rblLst.ClientID %> input[type=radio]").prop('checked',false);     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/). Also, [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate:

```
$('.checkboxlistid9').each(function (index, elem){
    $(elem).prop('checked',false);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.checkboxlistid9').removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is i-checks based dynamic radio button list

```
<table id="Body_TTBody_rblAttendanceStatus" class="i-checks rblStatus">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
    <div class="iradio_flat-red" style="position: relative;">
        <input id="Body_TTBody_rblAttendanceStatus_0" type="radio">
    </div>
    <label for="Body_TTBody_rblAttendanceStatus_0" class="">Absent</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <div class="iradio_flat-red" style="position: relative;">
        <input id="Body_TTBody_rblAttendanceStatus_1" type="radio">
    </div>
    <label for="Body_TTBody_rblAttendanceStatus_1" class="">Planned Leave</label> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
    <div class="iradio_flat-red" style="position: relative;">
        <input id="Body_TTBody_rblAttendanceStatus_2" type="radio">
    </div>
    <label for="Body_TTBody_rblAttendanceStatus_2" class="">Present</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <div class="iradio_flat-red" style="position: relative;">
        <input id="Body_TTBody_rblAttendanceStatus_3" type="radio">
    </div>
    <label for="Body_TTBody_rblAttendanceStatus_3" class="">Unplanned Leave</label> 
 </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery('#Body_TTBody_rblAttendanceStatus > tbody > tr> td').each(function (index, value) {
  if ($(value).find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked')) {
     $(value).find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
     $(value).find('input[type="radio"]').closest("div").removeClass("checked");
    }
});
</script>
```